# Condicionais "ligado" e "desligado" em um button C#

Tags: c#

Como por uma função secundaria em um botão ou elemento? Por exemplo :

```
private void Bnt1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{   
}

private void Bnt2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bnt.Enabled = false;
}
```

Nesse código, ao clicar em Bnt2 o primeiro botão fica desativado, como fazer para que ao clicar novamente em Bnt2 o Bnt1 volte a ficar ativo.

Ps: Se algo não ficou claro avisar e mudarei.

Ps2: A função secundaria se refere a parte da condicional, "senão".

Comment: O que você chama de função secundária de um botão? Seria disparar duas lógicas distintas ao mesmo tempo?

Comment: Eu me expressei mal Jefferson, quis falar sobre condicionais(if & else) mas acabei me confundindo.

Comment: Ah, agora entendi. Eu sei que a resposta do João Silva é exatamente sobre isso, mas ficaria ainda melhor se você colocasse isso na pergunta também, até para servir de base caso outra pessoa encontre sua mesma dificuldade

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Não entendi a parte de colocar 2 funções em um butão mas isso deve de servir.

```
private void Bnt2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(bnt.Enabled)
        bnt.Enabled = false;
    else
        bnt.Enabled = true;
}
```

Ou seguindo a sugestão do Jefferson Quesado:

```
private void Bnt2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //valor = ao inverso do valor atual
    bnt.Enabled = !bnt.Enabled;
}
```

Comment: Só que você misturou um pouco `bnt` e `btn`; como são só dois carácteres, não posso editar

Comment: Talvez fique mais elegante por `bnt.Enabled = !bnt.Enabled`? Assim o novo valor de habilitado sempre será o oposto do anterior, sem precisar navegar mais a fundo para saber o funcionamento

Comment: Sim, não reparei que tinha trocado o bnt e btn, realmente, não pensei nessa opção.